# Create a link that jumps to a certain location on the page

Tags: hyperlink

How can I email or text a [link](http://www.forceaerial.com) that activates a jumplink to an anchor?

I want to show people my showreel by directing them to my website via [link](http://www.forceaerial.com), but not make them have to scroll down to it.

Answer (score 0):

Add an id attribute to any element on your page:

```
<div id="something"></div>
```

Then add a # to the url and the id value:

http://example.com/page.html#something

Comment: I cant do that in wix can I? Can I create a link that I can email that directs to the anchor? My website is forceaerial.com and i want to create a link that automatically scrolls down to my showreel. Is this possible?

Comment: Wix? I don't know about Wix. You didn't say anything about using a specific CMS.

Comment: I tried to use every identifier in place of #something and it won't work. I'm not sure which ones will work and which ones won't. Do you know which one it is?

Comment: @mydoghoward You need to use the `id` attribute of the element you want to point to. In your case, you'd should be able to use `https://www.forceaerial.com#comp-iyhay3m2inlineContent`, but there's something in your theme which is rewriting the url to strip out the anchor part. So basically, the answer is no, you can't do it reliably with the theme you're using. From what I can tell anyway.